# Skype installation problem 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, skype, dependencies

After an `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, the following error appear:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'
>   to correct these. The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   skype-bin:i386 : Breaks: skype (< 4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) but
>   4.1.0.20-0ubuntu0.11.10.2 is installed E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

then I try `sudo apt-get -f install` and the following error appear:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The
>   following extra packages will be installed:   skype The following
>   packages will be upgraded:   skype 1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to
>   remove and 0 not upgraded. 1 not fully installed or removed. Need to
>   get 0 B/15.3 kB of archives. After this operation, 4,096 B disk space
>   will be freed. Do you want to continue [Y/n]?  dpkg: dependency
>   problems prevent configuration of skype:  skype-bin:i386
>   (4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) breaks skype (<<
>   4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) and is installed.   Version of skype to be configured is 4.1.0.20-0ubuntu0.11.10.2. dpkg: error processing
>   skype (--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured No
>   apport report written because the error message indicates its a
>   followup error from a previous failure.
>                                                                                                             Errors were encountered while processing:  skype E: Sub-process
>   /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

How can I update my skype and sort out this problem?

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and the following is showed in the graphical update manager.

> Changes for the versions: Installed version: 4.1.0.20-0ubuntu0.11.10.2
>   Available version: 4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi there has been several updates to skype in span of a day, try to do a --purge remove skype and reinstall. you can also install skype-bin if this doesn't work. It will give you latest skype.

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove skype` and then `sudo apt-get install skype` works, Thanks!

Comment: I think there were problems with packaging when they updated the repo to the latest version of Skype. When I tried to update yesterday, apt-get told me it wanted to update skype but it needed skype-bin and it wasn't in the repo. Today it worked.